# Setting class dinamically from inside a directive not working properly with ng-animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class, ng-animate

I'm loading a list of items from [this public API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users). After it loads the list, I apply a transition to the elements using:

```
/* ng-active */
.ng-enter{
    opacity: 0.2;
    padding-left: 30px;
    transition: all ease 1000ms;
}
.ng-enter-active{
    opacity: 1.0 ;
    padding-left: 0px ;
}
.ng-enter-stagger{
    transition-delay: 0.9s ;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.9s ;
    transition-duration: 0s ;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s ;
}
```

But, I need to change the `backgorund-color` in some items from inside a directive. To do that I'm using `ng-class` to call a function that make some logic to apply a specific class. This is the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('list', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: ''+
        '<div id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="value in values track by $index"'+
        'ng-class="getCSSClass(value.suite)">'+
        '<PRE><span class="id">{{value.id}}</span>'+
        '<span class="suite">({{value.suite}})</span>'+
        '<span class="aspace">°</span>[{{value.name}} , {{value.username}}] <br />'+
        '<span class="phone">{{value.phone}}</span><br/>'+
        '<span class="email">{{value.email}}, {{value.website}}</span></PRE>'+
        '</div>'+
        '',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.getCSSClass = function(suite) {
                return suite <= 500 ? "postBody backgr" : "postBody";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But in those items where the `backgorund-color` is changed, the animation is not applied correctly. This is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kSLqBkgtckDBbk4v5MCh?p=preview) where you can see the issue.

What I need is that all the items in the list, could be animated in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the background class selector to a separate `<div>` element so that is doesn't confuse the stagger animation:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('list', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: ''+
        '<div id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="value in values track by $index"'+
        //'class="postBody" ng-class="{backgr: value.suite<=500}">'+
        'class="postBody"><div ng-class="{backgr: value.suite<=500}">'+
        '<PRE><span class="id">{{value.id}}</span>'+
        '<span class="suite">({{value.suite}})</span>'+
        '<span class="aspace">°</span>[{{value.name}} , {{value.username}}] <br />'+
        '<span class="phone">{{value.phone}}</span><br/>'+
        '<span class="email">{{value.email}}, {{value.website}}</span></PRE>'+
        '</div></div>'+
        '',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.getCSSClass = function(suite) {
                //return suite <= 500 ? ["postBody", "backgr"] : "postBody";
                return suite <= 500 ? "backgr" : "";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/kXGFzWqkXnE2QCGmD4Yu?p=preview).

Comment: This one works. Excellent idea to create a new `div`, because it has logic. Thanks for your time in answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I it seems Problem with class I couldn't understand it , but alternative you can use style by defining it in the factory and bind it direct in style instead of class. it works.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .factory('dataService', function($http, $filter) {
    return {
      get: function() {
        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
        var events = [];
        return $http.get($filter('trusted')(url)).then(function(json) {
          angular.forEach(json.data, function(value, key) {
            var suite = value.address.suite.replace(/([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)/g, "$2");
            var obj = {
              'id': value.id,
              'name': value.name,
              'username': value.username,
              'email': value.email,
              'phone': value.phone,
              'website': value.website,
              'suite': suite,
              'style': suite <= 500 ? 'background-color: #FFEBBE; border: 1px dotted; border-color: #98bf21' : '',
              'state': false
            };

            events.push(obj); // Push en el array
          });

          return Promise.resolve(events);
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('list', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '' +
        '<div id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="value in values track by $index"' +
        'style="{{value.style}}">' +
        '<PRE><span class="id">{{value.id}}</span>' +
        '<span class="suite">({{value.suite}})</span>' +
        '<span class="aspace">°</span>[{{value.name}} , {{value.username}}] <br />' +
        '<span class="phone">{{value.phone}}</span><br/>' +
        '<span class="email">{{value.email}}, {{value.website}}</span></PRE>' +
        '</div>' +
        '',
      replace: true,
      controller: function($scope) {
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('loading', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div>' +
        '<br /><h2 class="blink">Getting Data from Server ...</h2>' +
        '<div class="loader">' +
        '<div class="dot"></div>' +
        '<div class="dot"></div>' +
        '<div class="dot"></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch('_loading', function(val) {
          if (val) {
            element.css('display', 'block');
          } else {
            element.css('display', 'none');
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .filter('trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(url) {
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
  }])
  .controller('PostsAjaxController', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.values = [];
    $scope._loading = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      getData();
    }, 1000);

    // The method
    function getData() {
      dataService.get().then(function handleResolve(resp) {
        $scope.values = resp;
        $scope._loading = false;
      });
    }

  });
```

```css
/* ng-active */

.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0.2;
  padding-left: 30px;
  transition: all ease 1000ms;
}

.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1.0;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.ng-enter-stagger {
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.9s;
  /*
 FROM THE DOCUMENTATION:
 In case the stagger doesn't work then these two values must be set
 to 0 to avoid an accidental CSS inheritance.
 */
  transition-duration: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #faf9f9;
  height: 250px;
}

.postBody {
  width: 350px;
  border-bottom: dashed 2px #9b9b9b;
  background-color: #faf9f9;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.backgr,.backgr2 {
  background-color: #FFEBBE;
  border: 1px dotted;
  border-color: #98bf21
}

.postBody:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.id {
  font-size: 2em;
  /*line-height: 1.3;
  font-weight: bold;*/
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.phone {
  display: inline-block;
}

.suite {
  font-size: 1em;
  /*line-height: 5.4;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  /*margin-left: 7px;*/
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.aspace {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2.7;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 24px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

.email {
  /*margin-left: 17px;
  font-style: italic;*/
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
  display: flex;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}


/* The loader container */

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 60%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  perspective: 200px;
  transform-type: preserve-3d;
}


/* The dot */

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 40px outset #1e3f57;
  transform-type: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
  background-color: transparent;
  animation: dot1 1000ms cubic-bezier(.49, .06, .43, .85) infinite;
}

.dot:nth-child(2) {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  border-width: 30px;
  border-color: #447891;
  animation-name: dot2;
  animation-delay: 75ms;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
}

.dot:nth-child(3) {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-color: #6bb2cd;
  animation-name: dot3;
  animation-delay: 150ms;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
}

@keyframes dot1 {
  0% {
    border-color: #1e3f57;
    transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #1e574f;
    transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(50deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: #1e3f57;
    transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
  }
}

@keyframes dot2 {
  0% {
    border-color: #447891;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #449180;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(50deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: #447891;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
  }
}

@keyframes dot3 {
  0% {
    border-color: #6bb2cd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #6bcdb2;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(50deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: #6bb2cd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transform: rotateX(24deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(-25px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-csp>

<head>
  <link data-require="angular-csp@1.7.5" data-semver="1.7.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/angular-csp.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <!-- <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> -->

  <script data-require="angular.js@1.7.5" data-semver="1.7.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate.js@1.7.5" data-semver="1.7.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap.js@2.5.0" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="services.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="directives.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="filters.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PostsAjaxController">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <loading></loading>
  <list></list>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Interesting approach and idea !

Comment: Why using the `class` attr does not works? Could be an `ng-animate` bug behavior?

Comment: No, it's not the animation, you can use empty class to test it `value.suite<=500?'test':'test2'` it dosen't work, but unfortunately I can't explain it.